# Python: My if and else commands aren't working... it always goes to if. How to fix?

Tags: python

Oh, man!  Sorry, I'm quite new to Python.  I was just being an idiot.  So don't answer this.

in Python I tried to use the if/else function, but it always chose the "if" option.  I use Python 2 (IDLE).  How can you help?  Here is my code:

```
if answer=="Yes" or "yes":
  upload_name=raw_input("What do you want to change it to? ")
elif answer=="No" or "no":
  print "Okay. Your name will remain as " + str(real_name) + "."
```

Answer (score 1):

`if answer=="Yes" or   answer== "yes":`

`elif answer=="No" or answer== "no":`

Or just use  `if answer.lower() == "yes"`

`or "yes"` always evaluates to `True` once the string is a non empty string, you are not comparing to answer, you are testing `bool("yes")`.

```
In [1]: bool("yes")
Out[1]: True
```

In your case I would just call lower on the string but if  you have multiple values to test against using `in` can be a nice way to do it:

```
if answer in {"Yes","yes"}:
```

Comment: Man, I should've known!  I'm new, so.. sorry.

Comment: @SpencerClayton, no worries, it is a simple mistake a lot of beginners make.